# Is $G_\Delta$ acting transitively on $\Delta$? ($\Delta$ is an imprimitive block )

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $G$ acts imprimitively (but transitively) on set $X$ and let $\Delta$ be some block of imprimitivity.
It should be clear, that $G_\Delta$ is acting transitively on $\Delta$, but I cannot see it.

Block stabilizer is defined: $G_\Delta=\{a\in G | \Delta^a=\Delta\}$.

I'm sure it will be a walk in the park for some of you.
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: When you say $G$ acts non-primitively on $X$, do you mean transitively but without nontrivial group blocks?

Comment: The standard term for this is *imprimitive*, which means transitive with nontrivial blocks. Assuming that $G$ is transitive, you just need to show that, for $x,y \in \Delta$, any element $g \in G$ with $x^g=y$ lies in $G_\Delta$, which is clear from the definition of a block.

Comment: Question is fixed. Derek: you are correct. If follows immediately from transitivity of G. Thank you!